# JavaFx 2.x : LineChart css axis Set Y Scale Side

Tags: css, javafx, linechart

In a code that plots a LineChart I have added a css string to choose either to display Y price scale to the right or left of the chart.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class XyChart extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
   stage.setTitle("Line plot");

   final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
   final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 21,0.1);

   yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
   yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
   yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);

   yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
        @Override
    public String toString(Number object){
            String label;
            label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            return label;
    }
});
final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

   lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
   lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
   lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

   XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 2.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 11));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));        

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(lineChart);          
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1); 

    String priceSide = "-fx-side: right;";

    Set<Node> axisNode = lineChart.lookupAll(".axis");
        for(final Node axis : axisNode){

            axis.setStyle(priceSide);
        }

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}   
}
```

I think I am missing something because the plotted line it is now all collapsed to the left side of the chart.

Just comment this part

```
String priceSide = "-fx-side: right;";

    Set<Node> axisNode = lineChart.lookupAll(".axis");
        for(final Node axis : axisNode){

            axis.setStyle(priceSide);
        }
```

and it plots correctly: same problem happens if I use

```
"-fx-side: left;";
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Comment: Found an alternative solution by using

yAxis.setSide(Side.RIGHT);